# Macro that copy pastes a fix range into another sheet and takes into consideration a cell value

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm pulling from Yahoo Finance the historical stock prices. You can only get with Power Query 100 lines. I have downloaded the history in one sheet and I have the Power Query with the last 100 days in another sheet. I would like to have a macro that pastes the new values into the history sheet only if they come after the values already saved in the history.

For example below in Table 0 it should only copy into Sheet1 the last month:

**Table 0**

[image: Table 0]

**Sheet1**

[image: picture]

My knowledge of VBA is quite basic, and I can only make a normal copy paste as below. Could any genius please help me with the correct and more complex VBA to achieve it?

```
Sub valuepaste()
Worksheets("AAPL").Range("Table_0").Copy
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You'll to add to your VBA code to to get the maximum date from table 1, then apply a filter to table 0, then you can use your copy/paste (although you should do that copy/paste at the end of your table 1 data).

Comment: Another option (one that I employed) is to get power query to look at your table 1 to get the last (max) date, use that to filter your data. Then you can just copy everything from your power query table to your table 1. Good luck.